# How To: Perform a MERGE/UPSERT from a parquet file staged on S3

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I was using below script to updated snowflake table staged with csv file.
Now I am trying  to do same merge/update by using parquet file.
I made some changes with respect to parquet file, but it was inserting **null** values in all the fields.

Below is script that i used for csv file, what exact changes i have to make for parquet file.

```
MERGE INTO foo USING
(SELECT $1 barKey,
 $2 newVal,
 $3 newStatus,
 ...
FROM @my_stage( FILE_FORMAT => 'csv', PATTERN => '.*my_pattern.*')
) bar ON foo.fooKey = bar.barKey
WHEN MATCHED THEN
 UPDATE SET val = bar.newVal, status = bar.newStatusWHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
 INSERT
 (val, status
 ) VALUES
 (bar.newVal, bar.newStatus
 );
```

Below Script i written for parquet file, but when i am executing it its inserts **null** values in all the fields.

```
    MERGE INTO data_architecture_stage.test ex USING ( 
SELECT $1:device_attr_hk, 
$1:applicationruntime_raw 
FROM @dss_prod.test.subscriber_data_solutions/rollup_parquet_expor2t/ (file_format => 'my_parquet_format', PATTERN => '.*.parquet') 
) ne ON ex.device_attr_hk = ne.$1:device_attr_hk 
WHEN MATCHED THEN 

UPDATE SET device_attr_hk = ne.$1:device_attr_hk , applicationruntime_raw = ne.$1:applicationruntime_raw 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
INSERT (device_attr_hk, applicationruntime_raw) VALUES (ne.$1:device_attr_hk, ne.$1:applicationruntime_raw);
```

**I want to know what exact changes do I have to make to execute the same script with a parquet file.**

Comment: Hi - what specific issue are you facing? If you can write a script for a csv file what issue are you facing converting it to read a parquet file, especially once you’ve read the documentation?

Comment: MERGE INTO  data_architecture_stage.test ex   USING (
SELECT
$1:device_attr_hk,
$1:applicationruntime_raw
FROM  @dss_prod.test.subscriber_data_solutions/rollup_parquet_expor2t/  (file_format => 'my_parquet_format', PATTERN => '.*.parquet')

) ne ON ex.device_attr_hk = ne.$1:device_attr_hk


WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET device_attr_hk = ne.$1:device_attr_hk
, applicationruntime_raw = ne.$1:applicationruntime_raw

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT
(device_attr_hk, applicationruntime_raw)
VALUES
(ne.$1:device_attr_hk, ne.$1:applicationruntime_raw);

Comment: @NickW Above script i written for parquet file, but when i executing this, its inserting null values in all the fields.I wants to know what wrong i am doing here.

Comment: If you try to run only the part: ```SELECT $1:device_attr_hk, 
$1:applicationruntime_raw 
FROM @dss_prod.test.subscriber_data_solutions/rollup_parquet_expor2t/ (file_format => 'my_parquet_format', PATTERN => '.*.parquet') ```, does it show any output?

Comment: @aek Yes, its returns proper result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes in existing script, And its working fine now.

```
MERGE INTO data_architecture_stage.test ex USING ( 
SELECT $1:device_attr_hk new_device_attr_hk, 
$1:applicationruntime_raw new_applicationruntime_raw 
FROM @dss_prod.test.subscriber_data_solutions/rollup_parquet_expor2t/ (file_format => 'my_parquet_format', PATTERN => '.*.parquet') 
) ne ON ex.device_attr_hk = new_device_attr_hk 
WHEN MATCHED THEN 

UPDATE SET device_attr_hk = ne.new_device_attr_hk , applicationruntime_raw = ne.new_applicationruntime_raw 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
INSERT (device_attr_hk, applicationruntime_raw) VALUES (ne.new_device_attr_hk, ne.new_applicationruntime_raw);
```